# Define Left coset of H in G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am preparing for exams and came across a past paper question which keeps on coming up, but I can't find anything for it in my lecture notes.

"Let G be a group and let H be a subgroup of it. Define the term left coset of
H in G. If gH and kH are left cosets with $gH ∩ kH \not= ∅ $ prove that gH = kH."

I roughly understand what cosets are but unsure how I would formally answer this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left coset of $g$ modulo $H$ is, by definition, the set $\;\{gh\mid h\in H\}$.

To prove that $gH=kH$ if $\;gH\cap kH\ne\varnothing$, you just have to prove that $g\in kH$, since this implies $H\subset kH$, whence by symmetry, $kH\subset gH$.

*A hint*:

$gH\cap kH\ne \varnothing$ means there exist $h, h'\in H$ such that $\;gh=kh'$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Sorry to leave this for so long! Would I then go on to say for $a \in H $ let $ga \in gH$. Then $ga = g h h^{-1} a = k h' h^{-1} a = k  h^* $. Hence $gH \subset kH$ ?